# Proof verification: Every set that contains a linearly dependent set is linearly dependent.

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

I wrote a proof for a theorem and would appreciate if someone could check if my proof is sound. Thanks a lot.

$Theorem$:

Every set that contains a linearly dependent set is linearly dependent.

$Proof$:

Let $S=\{v_1, v_2,...,v_k\}$ be a set of vectors. Let $L=\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_l\} \subset S$, $l \lt k$, be a linearly dependent subset of $S$.

Since $L$ is linearly dependent, there must exist, without loss of generality, $v_1 \in L$ such that

$$\sum_{i=2}^l \alpha_i v_i = v_1, \ \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then we can write a sum

$$\sum_{i=2}^l \alpha_i v_i + \sum_{i  = l+1}^k 0 v_i= v_1 =$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^k \alpha_i v_i = v_1$$
where $\alpha_i=0$ for $l+1 \lt i\lt k$.

Rearranging,
$$\sum_{i=2}^k \alpha_i v_i - v_1 = 0 \iff  \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i v_i = 0$$
with $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ not all zero.
Thus, the set $S$ is linearly dependent. This completes the proof.

Comment: Perfect!$\hspace{0pt}$

Comment: @TheoBendit Sure about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct. You actually did *not* use the fact that $L$ is linearly dependent at all. In the second paragraph of you proof, you should have written that, since $L$ is linearly dependente, there are numbers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_l\in\mathbb R$ *not all of which are* $0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^l\alpha_jv_j=0$.

Besides, you assumed that $S$ is finite, but the statement that you are trying to prove doesn't contain that assumption.

Comment: Thank you Jose! Assuming that $S$ is finite, and starting with: Since $L$ is linearly dependent, there must exist $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$ not all zero such that $\sum_{i=1}^l \alpha_i v_i = 0$, it follows that, without loss of generality, $v_1 = \sum_{i=2}^l \alpha_i v_i$. If I then continue with the rest of my proof, would that work?

Comment: Yes, it would be fine.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose on contrary let us consider a set S which is linearly independent and a subset T which is linearly dependent. Now we claim that every suset of linearly independent set is linearly independent
Now if it is singleton then we have done because every single vector is linearly independent And if it is not singleton then we have,suppose it is linearly dependent then there exit some scalars atleast one of them is non zero which is not possible. This shows that every suset of LI set is LI Since we have a subset T which is linearly dependent of a set S which is linearly independent then by above result S have to be linearly dependent which contradicts our assumption. Hence,every suset of LD is LD